# Query for the same value multiple times?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am trying to query a long list and I need the duplicates to show, currently I am only getting back one for each ID I search.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT
*
WHERE 
something."id" = '123' OR
something."id" = '123' OR
something."id" = '123' OR
something."id" = '123' OR
something."id" = '123'
```

When I try this I get back only the first row, ideally I would want to get back the same row 5 times. All of my searches come up with people who are trying to filter out duplicates which is the opposite of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Join a table where you have 123 five times.

Comment: Do you always want 5x or n rows or just for that specific ID? Join you a *numbers/tally* table with appropriate criteria.